# Create a Query to Combine Data from Two Tables while keep all data in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am doing a project, every second in 4 stations record a concentration data, so I have a very long list data of Time, Location, and Concentration in this original file.

I also have a file, which has the Longitude and Latitude of that four locations, so it's short. I don't want them show in my original file because it's too duplicated but sometime I may need to see them for other research.

I hope I can build to table in the Access, the original file and the coordinate file. If I need, I will build a Query to combine them. That table will be: Time, Location,Concentration, Longitude and Latitude.  I understand that a Query of Access is combining Data from two tables with similar structures, and ignore those elements without similar structures. Can I do something like keep all elements in Query and only apply coordinate into locations as two extra columns? Thanks.

Example
Original file:

```
Time                  Location      Concentration               
09/08/2017 10:02:13   Station1     12000   
09/08/2017 10:02:14   Station1     55000
......
......
09/08/2017 15:04:02   Station4     34333
```

Location file:

```
Location      Longitude     Latitude   
Station 1     98.8273928    -42.3374992
Station 2     98.7386783    -42.8498332
Station 3     98.6382994    -42.9372829
Station 4     98.4897393    -42.3943828
```

After build a Query, it should be looks like

```
 Time                  Location      Concentration   Longitude     Latitude             
09/08/2017 10:02:13   Station1       12000           98.8273928  -42.3374992 
09/08/2017 10:02:14   Station1       55000           98.8273928  -42.3374992
..........
..........
09/08/2017 15:04:02   Station4       34333           98.4897393  -42.3943828
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is one of the most fundamental queries, an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT OriginalFile.*, LocationFile.Longitude, LocationFile.Latitude
FROM OriginalFile
INNER JOIN LocationFile ON OriginalFile.Location = LocationFile.Location
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually my database is much more big and complicate than this but you made me know the basic idea.